# Scientific explanation of Skip Connections

Tags: deep-learning

I am searching for ***scientific work on skip-connections***.

Everybody is talking about improving gradient flow through the Network, which feels like it makes sense. But ***I would love to understand and read what that means when it comes down to the math***.

Other than the resnet [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) I haven't found anything in depth about those magical skip-connections.

I am looking for any hints, papers or equations.

Answer (score -1):

I recently read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.00388.pdf) which proposed a new technique without using skip-connections.It is proposed that the same accuracy can be achieved by increasing the width of the network rather than depth.